# multiple returned keys json

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework, angularjs-factory, angularjs-http

I have a joomla site running k2 and pulling info from it by adding format=json to the end of the string: https://www.example.com/posts?format=json which outputs something like this:

```
{
site: {
      url: "https://www.example.com",
      name: "mySite"
      },
category: {
          id: "67",
          name: "Gauteng",
          alias: "gauteng",
          link: "/tna/provincial/gauteng.html",
          parent: "66",
          extraFieldsGroup: "0",
          image: null,
          ordering: "1",
        events: {
          K2CategoryDisplay: ""
        },
        chidlren: []
       },
items: [{ 
         id="1",
         title="The Title",
         body="body content here..."
        },
        { 
         id="2",
         title="The Title",
         body="body content here..."
        }
}
```

now i am creating a service for this and just want to access "items".

```
.factory('Posts', function($http) {

  var posts = [];

  return {
        getPosts: function(){
            return $http.get("https://www.example.com/posts?format=json").then(function(response){
                posts = response;
                return posts;
            });
        },
        getPost: function(index){
            return posts[index];
        }
    }

});
```

it doesnt seem to be working though. is there any way to access just "items" with the call?

Comment: `posts = response.items`? [Object property accessors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors)

Comment: Indeed you need to reference the items property

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You post syntax should be `posts = response.data.items`

```
return $http.get("https://www.example.com/posts?format=json").then(function(response){
    posts = response.data.items; //items here
    return posts;
});
```

Comment: worked great. will accept answer when it lets me. Still too low to vote unfortunately

Comment: you still need to parse the json string, no?

Comment: You should also add a conditional to test that posts has been populated in your getPost. Otherwise it will not work unless getPosts is called and completed before getPost is called.

Comment: @downvoter could you please remove downvote as I updated answer

Comment: Actually you dont need to parse, as long as the server is outputting the correct content-type header, which Joomla does when the format parameter is json (at least in the 2.5+ versions dont know about the earlier ones)

Comment: The response.data property will be a JavaScript object or array so calling JSON.parse on it will throw an exception. I did not downvote, but please remove the call to JSON.parse it will throw an exception.

Comment: You are still saying that JSON.parse should be called. If the content type header was not set to application/json. Does that imply that we should try to parse it as JSON? that sounds like a bad idea. Check the docs here https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http

Comment: @AluanHaddad I updated the answer..& removed my comment from there

Comment: Glad to be of service